# Inverse of a permutation

Tags: algorithm, permutation

Say i have a function that calculates a permutation of a string. Call it `perm(in, seq)` where `in` is any string and `seq` is a string of length `strlen(str)` of numbers `0,1,2,3...`

`perm` outputs a string `out` where
`out[i] == in[perm[i]]`

Example:

```
perm("abc", "012") == "abc"
perm("abc", "210") == "cba"
perm("abc", "201") == "cab"
```

Now, I want to find the sequence `seq_c` which is the "inverse" of seq such that

`perm(perm(str, seq), seq_c) == str`

In other words, find the permutation sequence `sec_c` that transforms the permuted input back to the original input.

Comment: Brute forcing this would be easy, just check all the permutations. But finding the lets call it 'inverse'  is tougher I think. You somehow need to find the perm function inverse.

Comment: For n>10 this is already prohibititive, but yes inverse is a better name.

Comment: Sorry, i would like to know if my solution fits your needs or something wrong with it? In case `perm[i]` contains not an index, but letters and they are consecutive you can do `'b' - 'a'` to get index, if letters are not consecutive, you can use hashmap, theoretical running time still will be O(N). Of course, if string is big, there will be cache misses.

Answer (score 3):

```
array<int, 10> perm{ 2,7,4,9,8,3,5,0,6,1 };
array<int, 10> perm_inverse;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) perm_inverse[perm[i]] = i;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) cout << perm_inverse[i] << ",";
```

> 7,9,0,5,2,6,8,1,4,3,

Answer (score 0):

You could simply loop over the sequences and check for all sequences.

PSEUDO CODE:

```
While ( seq_c!= end )
{
if( perm(perm(str, seq), seq_c) == str)
return seq_c;
++seq_c;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would add up in complexity. Is there any specific programming language as some language provides builtin functionalities